# About moderncv footer

Tags: header-footer, moderncv

Is there any way I can turn off the footer from appearing in all but the last page of the CV? (and once again in the cover letter). Is a nice idea that even with just the first page they could call you, but I need the space. I've already modified the template in order to do so, but I wanna try to keep my cv as vanilla as possible.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}

% content

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{1998-2007}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\pagebreak % just to simulate a lenghty CV for this MWE

\section{Computer skills}
Second page

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Still. Please add some MWE here.

Comment: Tried to reduce it as much as possible. Check the new example at: http://pastebin.com/c77kCLKb

Comment: Hem... You're the one asking for help here, and yet you expect others to do the tedious work. The least you could do is post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). I insist.

Comment: Posting the MWE in the question as suggested

Comment: Done, formatting wasn't good because I didn't add a newline before that line

Answer (score 10):

If I understand correctly, you want the footer only in the last page.

This can be achieved in the following way:

1. Put `\pagestyle{empty}` just after `\makecvtitle` to remove the footer from all pages.
2. Put `\thispagestyle{plain}` just before `\end{document}`. This ensures that the last page has the footer (note that `moderncv` redefines and uses the `plain` style).

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}

% content

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\pagestyle{empty}

\section{Education}
\cventry{1998-2007}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\pagebreak % just to simulate a lenghty CV for this MWE

\section{Computer skills}
Second page

\thispagestyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To remove extra white space from footer you can also use

```
\usepackage[scale=0.75, top=1cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
```

Add/Edit the above code at the beginning of your Latex file. Setting "bottom" length is doing the wonders over here.

After adding this your code should look something like this

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        

% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            
\moderncvcolor{black}                              
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         
\nopagenumbers{}                                  

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75, top=1cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           

\usepackage{import}
```

Comment: This pushes down the footer across all pages. The OP is requesting something more particular, not really a global change. And why also adjust `top`?