# Footer disappears in moderncv v2

Tags: header-footer, moderncv, german

When I inserted a box with personal information besides the portrait in moderncv with [this method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231388/howto-insert-text-beside-of-the-portrait-in-moderncv-casual-style/334605#answer-231411), the footer disappears (contained contact options). When the code from `\makeatletter` to `\makeatother` is removed, the personal information is above my portrait, and the footer appears again.

In the original CV.pdf from *gloschtla*, there is a footer. But when i build & view his original CV.tex in TeXstudio, his footer disappears, too.

[includeheadfoot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100402/my-footer-disappears-when-i-increase-headheight#answer-100403) didn't help, either.

I just installed Linux Mint 18 and [texlive-full](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/TeX_Live/#Installation). Is it possible, that not all packages are installed properly?

here my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,unicode,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{pdfpages}       %http://www.sascha-frank.com/Faq/include_pdf.html & http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf
\usepackage[scale=0.8,top=3.0cm,bottom=3.0cm]{geometry} % scale widens the margins, top=1cm moves the whole up
%\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.9cm}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage[includeheadfoot,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}

%CV-Name-Schriftgröße ändern:
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{26}{8}\mdseries\upshape}
% Quelle: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128052/font-size-in-moderncv

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162568/how-to-change-date-format-to-german
\newdateformat{myformat}{\THEDAY{. }\monthname[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR}


% begin of inserted 1st block http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231388/howto-insert-text-beside-of-the-portrait-in-moderncv-casual-style#answers-header
\makeatletter  
\def\insertpersonalinformation#1{\def\@insertpersonalinformation{#1}}
% commands
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
\recomputecvlengths%
  % ensure footer with personal information
\makecvfooter%
  % optional picture
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
  {}%
  {%
       \setlength\fboxrule{\@photoframewidth}%
       \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
         \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
       {\color{color1}\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}}%
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  % name
  \@initializelength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}%
  \settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \parbox[b]{\textwidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{%
%\raggedleft%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@insertpersonalinformation}}
      {\raggedleft}
      {\hspace*{10pt}{\personalinfofont\@insertpersonalinformation}\hfill}% alternate design: \MakeLowercase
    {\namefont{\color{color2!50}\@firstname} {\color{color2}\@lastname}}
  }
  {\color{color2!50}\rule{\textwidth}{.25ex}}%
  % optional title
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\null\hfill\titlestyle{\@title}}\\[2.5em]% \null is required as there is no box on the line after \\, so glue (and leaders) disappears; this is in contrast to after \par, where the next line starts with an indent box (even after \noindent).
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\null\hfill\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\hfill\null\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \maketitle
\makeatother

\def\personalinfofont{\normalfont\small}
% end of inserted 1st block http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231388/howto-insert-text-beside-of-the-portrait-in-moderncv-casual-style#answers-header


%\title{emty}
\firstname{Max}
\familyname{Mustermann}

\photo[100pt][0.1pt]{Portrait-MaxMustermann.jpg}                             % '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file; optional, remove the line if not wanted


\usepackage{etoolbox} % http://tex.aspcode.net/view/635399273629833626153770/increase-spacing-in-closing-of-cover-letter-in-moderncv
\patchcmd{\makeletterclosing}{3em}{1em}{}{} % reducing the space betweeen greetings and name in application writing from the original 3em to 1em

\begin{document}

% begin of inserted 2nd block http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231388/howto-insert-text-beside-of-the-portrait-in-moderncv-casual-style#answers-header
\insertpersonalinformation{%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{2cm}%<- adjust here
  \raggedright
  \textbf{Geburt:} date, \textnormal{\textit{City}} \\
  \textbf{Familienstand:} – \\
  \end{minipage}%
}
% end of inserted 2nd block http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231388/howto-insert-text-beside-of-the-portrait-in-moderncv-casual-style#answers-header

\address{street}{city}
\phone[mobile]{+49 152 12345}
\email{mm@mail.de}

\AfterPreamble{\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={Max Mustermann},
  pdftitle={Lebenslauf | Max Mustermann},
  pdfsubject={tabellarischer Lebenslauf}
    }}


\maketitle 
%\thispagestyle{empty} %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44280/pagestyleempty-doesnt-seem-to-work-for-page-with-maketitle
\vspace*{-8mm} %reduces the space between header and the first CV section
%\pagestyle{empty} % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147849/about-moderncv-footer


\section{Bildungsweg}
%\cventry{year--year}{Abschluss}{Schulname}{Ortname}{\textit{Note}}
[…]


%\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen,\\\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{signature.png}}
```

Here the log:

```
Undefined control sequence. \vspace
You have requested package `moderncvheadii', but the package provides `moderncvheadii'.
You have requested package `moderncvbodyi', but the package provides `moderncvbodyi'.
You have requested package `moderncvfooti', but the package provides `moderncvfooti'.
Over-specification in `v'-direction.
Overfull \hbox (9.46065pt too wide) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (5.55536pt too wide) in paragraph
```

---

For the completion, with the old synthax "makecvfooter" you get this confusing error:
! Undefined control sequence.\maketitle ->\recomputecvlengths \makecvfooter\newsbox ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace `\makecvfooter` with `\makecvfoot`.

[in `moderncv v2` it's `\makecvfoot`](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/18811/footer-verschwindet-in-moderncv).

Comment: perhaps, someone could edit [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231388/howto-insert-text-beside-of-the-portrait-in-moderncv-casual-style?answertab=active#tab-top), i don't have enough reputation in order to comment there…